# Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

when i run below command in my terminal it shows below code instead of routes

```
php artisan route:list



 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/login">http://localhost/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]          Fatal
>   error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run `php artisan route:list` if any of the routes and their related controllers have errors.

In this case, it looks like you have a controller that has an error which is that you're using the `Redirect` facade without importing it first, so it's looking for the `Redirect` class in the same namespace as the controller, i.e. `App\Http\Controllers\Redirect`.

Locate the class that is using the `Redirect` facade and add `Use Redirect` to the top of the file and that should sort it hopefully!

Answer (score 29):

The only thing that you have to do is to add:

```
use Redirect;
```

in your controller just after `namespace` line or put `\` before you call `Redirect::` i.e.:

```
return \Redirect::back();
```

Comment: What Redirect Class will this assign? If I try to find the assigned class in my IDE it does not match anything ...

Answer (score 21):

You have to import the class. This is the one you need:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `\` before Redirect the function

return `\Redirect::back();`

It works fine for me in laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1):

I use in Laravel 8 this:

```
return redirect()->back();
```